# Assigning multiple dates to javascript object keys result in the same values for all of them

Tags: javascript

When I execute this code:

```
var a = {
    b: Date.now(),
    c: Date.now(),
    d: Date.now(),
}
console.log(a);
```

My console shows me that the milliseconds since 1970 for the `b`, `c` and `d` keys of `a` are the same.

Does this mean that these three keys are all assigned in less than a millisecond? Or is the javascript interpreter just calculating it once and assigning it to all keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those three keys are all assigned in less than a millisecond. Simple operations are done immediately and there is no difference you can see in ms. To see a bigger difference you can check it eg. by doing some stress-test like generating random 100.000.000 times in a loop and set time before and after loop.